# How to Create a .NET Web Service based on a fixed WSDL that supports multiref deserialization

Tags: .net, web-services, serialization, soap

Background:  We have a "business partner" that has a java client they use to hook up to a java/Axis-based web service. They want to use the same client to send us data, so we need to "mimic" that web service. They provided a WSDL, sample SOAP request, and sample SOAP response *(Side note: the WSDL was auto-generated and 46,000+ lines long)*. The issue is we are a .NET shop.

I've attempted both ASMX web service using WSDL.exe and WCF web service using SVCUTIL.exe *(the proxy classes generated by both are giant)*.  Neither implementation, however, will support the sample SOAP request because it contains **multiref** references that the .NET serializers don't seem to understand, and it throws an InvalidOperationException any time the value it's trying to read is an Enum in the proxy class.

I've researched this extensively, and most of the postings refer to a .NET client reading multiref responses while consuming an AXIS-generated web service.  In those postings, they were at least able to read the responses -- I can't even get that far yet.

I have to operate under the assumption that the business partner cannot make any changes to the client other than changing the url of the service.

If I need to provide an example/more info I will, but my question is quite simple enough *(although the answer most likely is not)*:  **Is there any way to generate .NET "server-side" web service proxy classes that support "multiref" deserialization?**

*Other ideas I've had to solve this issue:*

- Write my own proxy class
- Override the serialization behavior in the proxy classes *(probably not feasible because of the 70,000 lines)*
- Create a REST service instead and manually parse the SOAP request *(so far this is the solution I'm leaning toward unless I can find something better)*

Comment: Ignore ASMX and WSDL.EXE. Try to create a client using SVCUTIL. You should then be able to create a service that implements the service contract generated from the WSDL

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I had already used svcutil.exe to generate a service contract and created a WCF web service implementing that contract -- still have deserialization issue with the multirefs.

Comment: Did svcutil also produce a config file? The configuration should contain the information necessary to _consume_ the service; I presume you would need similar configuration to _emulate_ the service.